# Unable to read csv file present in Unix in Python

Tags: python, csv, unix, jenkins

I want to read CSV file which is present in `Unix` at a path say-`/var/lib/Folder/abc.csv`

I am using below code to read this file, but it looks like it's not returning any rows and hence it's not going inside the **for** loop.

```
file_path = "/var/lib/Folder/abc.csv"

with open(file_path, newline='') as csv_file:
   reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
   for row in reader:
      logging.debug(str(datetime.datetime.now()) + " Checking rows...")
      logging.debug(str(datetime.datetime.now()) + " Row(" + str(count) + ") = " + row)
```

CSV file looks something like-

```
"Account ID","Detail","Description","Date created" 

"123456","Customer","Savings","2017/10/24"
```

I am using Python **2.7**

This works when i try in my local. But I am actually using Jenkins to run this and the file is placed in my Jenkins Master server. I have copied that file from the code server to jenkins using below - with ssh_shell.open(path + fileName, "rb") as remote_file: with open(path + fileName, "wb") as local_file: shutil.copyfileobj(remote_file, local_file) After this I am trying to read the file, its not working. i.e not going inside that for loop. Any idea on that?

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example that reproduces your problem. How does your csv-file look like? Anything special? What about the `reader`? Can you e.g. just plot the first row? - That's how you should approach a problem... So please, give us some more hints.

Comment: Are you using python 2 or 3?

Comment: Can you please share the error that you encountered!

Comment: It is not throwing any error. But since the file has some content, I expect that to be written in log  "logging.debug(str(datetime.datetime.now()) + " Row(" + str(count) + ") = " + row)" . It is not writing it. So I suspect its not entering the for loop. Rest of the code and logging is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
```

Also, please try to see what "reader" actually contains. If the for loop is not entered that means that the contents have not been read correctly. Try to start debugging from there.

Comment: I tried csv_file.readline() - its printing blank. Does it mean there is problem with the way i am opening the file?

Comment: Did you try my suggestion?

Comment: I am asking whether you tried my suggestion about setting the delimiter explicitly.
For testing the reader just do print(reader) and see what the outcome is.

Comment: Try the following:

with open(file_path) as csv_file:
   reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
   for row in reader:
      print(row)

Comment: This works when i try in my local. But I am actually using Jenkins to run this and the file is placed in my Jenkins Master server. I have copied that file from the code server to jenkins using below -

 with ssh_shell.open(path + fileName, "rb") as remote_file:
                            with open(path + fileName, "wb") as local_file:
                                shutil.copyfileobj(remote_file, local_file)

After this I am trying to read the file, its not working. i.e not going inside that for loop. Any idea on that?

Answer (score 0):

try this changed `row` to `str(row)`

```
file_path = "/var/lib/Folder/abc.csv"

with open(file_path, newline='') as csv_file:
   reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
   for row in reader:
      logging.debug(str(datetime.datetime.now()) + " Checking rows...")
      logging.debug(str(datetime.datetime.now()) + " Row(" + str(count) + ") = " + str(row))
```